# Parsing BLAST output in XML format using Regular Expression

Tags: python, regex, bioinformatics

There many other better ways to parse BLAST output in .xml format, but I was curious to try using regex, even if it is not so straightforward and common. Here is the code how to extract translated query sequences from BLASTX output in fasta format.

```
################
fasta_out = True
#################
import re
import sys
base = sys.argv[1]
base = base.rstrip('xml')
if fasta_out == True:
    seq_out = open(base+'fasta', 'w')
read_def = set()

with open(sys.argv[1],'rb') as xml:
    for line in xml:
        if re.search('<Iteration_query-def>', line) != None:
            line = line.strip()
            line = line.rstrip()
            line = re.sub('<Iteration_query-def>', '', line)
            line = re.sub('</Iteration_query-def>', '', line)
            query_def = line
        if re.search('<Hit_def>', line) != None:
            line = line.strip()
            line = line.rstrip()
            line = re.sub('<Hit_def>', '', line)
            line = re.sub('</Hit_def>', '', line)
            hit_def = line[:line.index(' ')]
        if re.search('<Hsp_query-frame>', line) != None:
            line = line.strip()
            line = line.rstrip()
            line = re.sub('<Hsp_query-frame>', '', line)
            line = re.sub('</<Hsp_query-frame>', '', line)
            frame = line
        if re.search('<Hsp_qseq>', line) != None:
            if query_def not in read_def:
                read_def.add(query_def)
                line = line.strip()
                line = line.rstrip()
                line = re.sub('<Hsp_qseq>', '', line)
                line = re.sub('</Hsp_qseq>', '', line)
                seq = line
                if fasta_out == True:
                    print >> seq_out, '>'+query_def+' '+hit_def+'\n'+seq
if fasta_out == True:
    seq_out.close()
```

Input sample

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE BlastOutput PUBLIC "-//NCBI//NCBI BlastOutput/EN" "http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/dtd/NCBI_BlastOutput.dtd">
<BlastOutput>
  <BlastOutput_program>blastx</BlastOutput_program>
  <BlastOutput_version>blastx 2.2.21 [Jun-14-2009]</BlastOutput_version>
  <BlastOutput_reference>~Reference: Altschul, Stephen F., Thomas L. Madden, Alejandro A. Schaffer, ~Jinghui Zhang, Zheng Zhang, Webb Miller, and David J. Lipman (1997), ~&quot;Gapped BLAST and PSI-BLAST: a new generation of protein database search~programs&quot;,  Nucleic Acids Res. 25:3389-3402.</BlastOutput_reference>
  <BlastOutput_db>Triticum_aestivum.pep.all.fa</BlastOutput_db>
  <BlastOutput_query-ID>lcl|1_0</BlastOutput_query-ID>
  <BlastOutput_query-def>contig1</BlastOutput_query-def>
  <BlastOutput_query-len>1506</BlastOutput_query-len>
  <BlastOutput_param>
    <Parameters>
      <Parameters_matrix>BLOSUM62</Parameters_matrix>
      <Parameters_expect>0.001</Parameters_expect>
      <Parameters_gap-open>11</Parameters_gap-open>
      <Parameters_gap-extend>1</Parameters_gap-extend>
      <Parameters_filter>F</Parameters_filter>
    </Parameters>
  </BlastOutput_param>
  <BlastOutput_iterations>
    <Iteration>
       <Iteration>
      <Iteration_iter-num>1</Iteration_iter-num>
      <Iteration_query-ID>lcl|1_0</Iteration_query-ID>
      <Iteration_query-def>contig1</Iteration_query-def>
      <Iteration_query-len>1506</Iteration_query-len>
      <Iteration_hits>
        <Hit>
          <Hit_num>1</Hit_num>
          <Hit_id>gnl|BL_ORD_ID|37668</Hit_id>
          <Hit_def>Traes_4BL_9859F0705.1 pep:novel scaffold:IWGSP1:IWGSC_CSS_4BL_scaff_7021186:3087:16040:1 gene:Traes_4BL_9859F0705 transcript:Traes_4BL_9859F0705.1 description:&quot;&quot;</Hit_def>
          <Hit_accession>37668</Hit_accession>
          <Hit_len>1032</Hit_len>
          <Hit_hsps>
            <Hsp>
              <Hsp_num>1</Hsp_num>
              <Hsp_bit-score>1021.92</Hsp_bit-score>
              <Hsp_score>2641</Hsp_score>
              <Hsp_evalue>0</Hsp_evalue>
              <Hsp_query-from>1</Hsp_query-from>
              <Hsp_query-to>1506</Hsp_query-to>
              <Hsp_hit-from>210</Hsp_hit-from>
              <Hsp_hit-to>711</Hsp_hit-to>
              <Hsp_query-frame>1</Hsp_query-frame>
              <Hsp_identity>501</Hsp_identity>
              <Hsp_positive>501</Hsp_positive>
              <Hsp_align-len>502</Hsp_align-len>       
              <Hsp_qseq>LAVDSEFNQVLQSDSCRLYQLQSHTCSQGHPLNRFTWGNKKSLSNAMGSGINLREEILQMYMSNYHGGMMKLVIIGGEPLDTLEAWTMELFSEVKAGPLLEISPKTDMPFWKSGKLHKLEAVRDVHSLFLSWTLPCLHKEYMKKPEDYLAHLLGHEGKGSLLYFLKAKGWASTLSAGVGTGGTQRSSYAYIFEMSIRLSDSGLKNLFEVITAVYQYINLLKQSEPQEWIFKELQDIGYMEFRFAEEQPPDDYVVDLAENMLFYSEKHIISGEYIYEGWEPELVKHVLSFFHPDNMRVDILSRSFDKQSQAIRCEPWFGSQYIEEDIPSSLIESWRNPVEIDGNFHLPRKNEYIPGDFSLRNASIPKSSNDDNPRCIVDEPFIKLWHKMDITFNVPRANAYFLISVKDGCSSLRNSVLTDLFANLLKDELNEVLYQAYVAKLETSLSVVGSNLELKLYGYNDKLAILLSHILAASQSFSPKIDRFEVIKEDLERAYRNTNMKP</Hsp_qseq>
              <Hsp_hseq>LAVDSEFNQVLQSDSCRLYQLQSHTCSQGHPLNRFTWGNNKSLSNAMGSGINLREEILQMYMSNYHGGMMKLVIIGGEPLDTLEAWTMELFSEVKAGPLLEISPKTDMPFWKSGKLHKLEAVRDVHSLFLSWTLPCLHKEYMKKPEDYLAHLLGHEGKGSLLYFLKAKGWASTLSAGVGTGGTQRSSYAYIFEMSIRLSDSGLKNLFEVITAVYQYINLLKQSEPQEWIFKELQDIGYMEFRFAEEQPPDDYVVDLAENMLFYSEKHIISGEYIYEGWEPELVKHVLSFFHPDNMRVDILSRSFDKQSQAIRCEPWFGSQYIEEDIPSSLIESWRNPVEIDGNFHLPRKNEYIPGDFSLRNASIPKSSNDDNPRCIVDEPFIKLWHKMDITFNVPRANAYFLISVKDGCSSLRNSVLTDLFANLLKDELNEVLYQAYVAKLETSLSVVGSNLELKLYGYNDKLAILLSHILAASQSFSPKIDRFEVIKEDLERAYRNTNMKP</Hsp_hseq>
              <Hsp_midline>LAVDSEFNQVLQSDSCRLYQLQSHTCSQGHPLNRFTWGN KSLSNAMGSGINLREEILQMYMSNYHGGMMKLVIIGGEPLDTLEAWTMELFSEVKAGPLLEISPKTDMPFWKSGKLHKLEAVRDVHSLFLSWTLPCLHKEYMKKPEDYLAHLLGHEGKGSLLYFLKAKGWASTLSAGVGTGGTQRSSYAYIFEMSIRLSDSGLKNLFEVITAVYQYINLLKQSEPQEWIFKELQDIGYMEFRFAEEQPPDDYVVDLAENMLFYSEKHIISGEYIYEGWEPELVKHVLSFFHPDNMRVDILSRSFDKQSQAIRCEPWFGSQYIEEDIPSSLIESWRNPVEIDGNFHLPRKNEYIPGDFSLRNASIPKSSNDDNPRCIVDEPFIKLWHKMDITFNVPRANAYFLISVKDGCSSLRNSVLTDLFANLLKDELNEVLYQAYVAKLETSLSVVGSNLELKLYGYNDKLAILLSHILAASQSFSPKIDRFEVIKEDLERAYRNTNMKP</Hsp_midline>
```

Comment: FYI : It is considered a bad idea to (try to) parse languages like XML with regexp. You'll find loads of interesting explanations online like http://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/ or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8577060/why-is-it-such-a-bad-idea-to-parse-xml-with-regex .

Comment: This being said, it might be interesting to give an example of input.

Comment: It worked on my huge file, it is not the best idea, but not absurd, DYT? :) Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Redundancy

You have a lot of redundant code that you repeat several times.

1. You can move these lines:

   ```
   line = line.strip()
   line = line.rstrip()
   ```

   to immediately after `for line in xml:`. This saves you from having to `strip` in each if-statement.
2. As pointed out above, you use `strip` **and** `rstrip`. This is also redundant: `strip` removes **both** leading and trailing characters from the string, while `rstrip` removes only trailing characters. So unless you are removing extra trailing characters (which it seems you aren't) `rstrip` is not needed.
3. Your `re.sub` statements can be compacted into one statement using the pipe operator (`a|b`) which searches for both `a` and `b`:

   ```
   line = re.sub('<Hit_def>|</Hit_def>', '', line)
   ```
4. What is `frame` doing? In your code snippet, it serves no purpose.
5. Your `re.search` functions are not needed. If you do `re.sub` on a string and the pattern you gave it does not find a match, it will simply return the original string:

   ```
   >>>foo = 'Hello World!'
   >>>foo = re.sub('apples', 'oranges', foo)
   >>>foo
   'Hello World!'
   ```

   Another problem with this is, in its current state, your code could throw a `NameError` because one of the variables `query_def, hit_def, frame, seq` may not have been defined:

   ```
   if re.search('<Hsp_qseq>', line) != None:
       # I will error out because if the line didn't contain `<Iteration_query-def>`
       # `query_def` was never created!
       if query_def not in read_def:
   ```

### Order

`import`s always go at the top.

### If-Statements

While your statements are technically correct, they can be made more pythonic by excluding the `== True` and `!= None`:

```
# This is the same as...
foo = True
if foo:

# ...this
if foo == True:
```

Also, your statements may be able to be changed into `elif`s depending on whether a single line can contain multiple of the tags you are looking for. If not, then `elif`s will help you performace quite a bit.

Another note, if

### String Formatting

The most pythonic and preferred way to create strings is to use `str.format`:

```
foo = '{} {}!'.format('Hello', 'World')
```

Using this method in your application will remove all of the messy string concatenation:

```
print >> seq_out, '>{} {}\n{}'.format(query_def, hit_def, seq)
```

### Files

I am going to assume that you need to run the parsing no matter what and only print to `seq_out` if `fasta_out` is `True`. With that being said, instead of writing to the file each time, which requires you to use the insecure `open()` and `close()` functions, we will simply create a single string which you will write once at the very end:

```
seq_body_text = ''
with open(sys.argv[1],'rb') as xml:
    for line in xml:
        # Yadda yadda....do regex stuff
            ...
        if fasta_out:
            new_line = '>{} {}\n{}'.format(query_def, hit_def, seq)
            seq_body_text = '{}{}\n'.format(seq_body_text, new_line)

# Once the whole file is parsed, write the body text.
if fasta_out:
    with open(seq_out, 'w') as file:
        file.write(seq_body_text)
```

---

Here is my version of your code.

> **NOTE:** I assume each line can have each of the tags. However, I could have assumed wrong because your logical structure was slightly muddy.

```
import re
import sys

base = sys.argv[1]
base = base.rstrip('xml')

fasta_out = True
read_def = set()
with open(sys.argv[1],'rb') as xml:
    for line in xml:
        line = line.strip()

        line = re.sub('<Iteration_query-def>|</Iteration_query-def>', '', line)
        query_def = line

        if query_def not in read_def:
            read_def.add(query_def)

            if fasta_out:
                # Why compute these lines in the main loop? Move them here
                # and save computation.
                line = re.sub('<Hit_def>|</Hit_def>', '', line)
                hit_def = line[:line.index(' ')]

                line = re.sub('<Hsp_query-frame>|</Hsp_query-frame>', '', line)
                line = re.sub('<Hsp_qseq>|</Hsp_qseq>', '', line)
                seq = line

                new_line = '>{} {}\n{}'.format(query_def, hit_def, seq)
                seq_body_text = '{}{}\n'.format(seq_body_text, new_line)


# Once the whole file is parsed, write the body text.
if fasta_out:
    with open('{}{}'.format(base, 'fasta'), 'w') as file:
        file.write(seq_body_text)
```

Comment: This is an awesome review of the code, very clear and detailed! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to parse xml file with python regex, you should match against whole file, not per lines. For example:

```
matched = re.search("<Hit_def>(.*?)</Hit_def>", wholexml, re.S)
if matched: print matched.group(1)
```

Here you have tutorial for advanced regex: http://www.cofoh.com/advanced-regex-tutorial-python

But regex for xml is a bad idea. It should be done by xml library. In the above example you have to even deal with special XML characters (& quot;, ...)

Happy bioinformatics !